# Overload ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, stream, operator-overloading

I am trying to read complex numbers of the form x + y*i from a file which looks like this:

```
2 + 3i

4 + 5i
```

If I implement it like this it only works for the first line and I would like to be able to read again in the same manner the second line. Any ideas?

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Complex& c) {
    in >>  c.r >> c.i;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: There is a plus in you file format

Comment: How is "+ 3i" parsed :D

Comment: @DieterLücking The plus is understood as the sign of the second number, and is thus OK. The problem is the last "i".

Comment: Honestly I'd use getline() and then do scanf on the resulting line to parse the exact format you want.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Do not throw exceptions directly, as this is not the usual way of doing thing with iostreams.

EDIT: Process the sign character separately so that spaces in the input are allowed.

A quick and dirty solution:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Complex& c)
{
    char sign;
    char suffix;
    in >> c.r >> sign >> c.i >> suffix;
    if ((sign != '+' && sign != '-') || suffix != 'i') {
        in.setstate(ios::failbit);
    }
    if (sign == '-') {
        c.i = -c.i;
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: I did something similar indeed but I am not quite happy since it is not general or instructive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you read both the "+" and the "i" when processing the input.

The following implementation works:

```
struct complex
{
    double r;
    double i;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, complex& c)
{
    char plus, i;

    in >> c.r >> plus >> c.i >> i;

    return in;
}

std::string initdata = "2 + 3i\n4 + 5i\n";

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss(initdata);
    std::vector<complex> values;
    std::istream_iterator<complex> begin(ss), end;

    std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter<std::vector<complex>>(values));
}
```

Comment: You would eliminate the minus sign of the imaginary part.

Comment: @YongweiWu Well the variable `plus` should have been called `sign`. And as the data was presented there is a space between the sign and the imaginary part so they have to be parsed separately - it cannot be part of the number. This code was compiled and tested before posting. The only other change I would make would be to set the fail bit if the `sign` or `i` parameter in the `operator>>` do not have the correct values.

Comment: Oh, I missed the space problem. I need to correct my answer to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this :

```
#include <iostream>

struct complex
{
    int r, i;
};

int main ()
{
    complex co;
    char c;

    while ((std::cin >> co.r >> c /* '+' */ >> co.i >> c /* 'i' */))
    {
        std::cout << co.r << ' ' << co.i << "i\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::istringstream s(
        "2 + 3i\n"
        "4 + 5i\n"
    );
    char sgn;
    double r;
    double i;
    while(s >> r >> sgn >> i) {
        if(s.get() != 'i') {
            std::cerr << "Missing i\n";
            return -1;
        }
        std::cout << r << sgn << i << "i\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: The space before the imaginary part and the trailing i are breaking the input.